# Rasberry Pi 4 に Ubuntu MATE を入れたいのですが、途中で止まってしまいます

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

Rasberry Pi 4 8GBにUbuntu MATEを入れたいのですが、ダウンロードが終わった後何も起きません。マウスカーソルは動くのですが、クラッシュ（多分していると思います）して動きません。RAMは8GBあるので問題ないと思うのですが。

あと、ほかの方は以下のように表示されるはずなんですけど、表示されません。なんか、画像が表示されずにUbuntu MATEって表示されて下にかなり画質のあらい点が表示されている感じになります。

[image]

↑こうなるはずなんですが、僕の場合
[image]
↑こうなります。ラズベリーパイイメージャーっていう公式の使っているんですが...。
あと、設定が終わった後に再起動するはずなんですが、再起動せずに、ずっとそのままなにも動きません。3回ほど試してみたんですが、（SDcard初期化->書き込んで設定という流れを）うまくいきません。ラズベリーパイイメージャーでの操作は、SDcardとか必要なことを選択->ダウンロードしてきたファイルを選択（ubuntuMATEの）->ラズパイ4を選択->書き込み->設定しますか？みたいなのを「いいえ」とやっていってるのですが...。
どうしてでしょうか。参考にしたサイトは、[このサイト](https:///invisiblepotato.com/raspberrypi11/)です。

Comment: 実際にどのような手順で作業したのかをもう少し詳しく記載してください。何か参考にした手順があるようなら、それらへのリンクもある方がよいです。

Comment: 一般的には PCに [rpi-imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/)をインストール, そのアプリ使ってSDインストール手順踏めばよいだけ。`rpi-imager` 使っていないならどのような手順だったか, `rpi-imager` 使ったのならどのように操作したのか。それを記さないと「あー失敗したんだね」で終わりです。問題点指摘のしようがない

Comment: 「設定が終わった後に再起動するはず」とは何のことを指してますか？ ユーザー名＆パスワード登録のことですか？ それともそれ以前の何か？
「設定しますか？みたいなのを「いいえ」とやって」これも何のことか不明。
またダウンロードした `ubuntu-mate-22.04-desktop-arm64+raspi.img.xz` ファイルは Checksum確認していますか？ SHA256 で `3b538f8462cdd957acfbab57f5d949faa607c50c3fb8e6e9d1ad13d5cd6c0c02`のはず

Answer (score 0):

おおよそ次のようなステップで, インストール作業が進みます

PC側 (rpi-imager version 1.7.2)

- 「書き込む」ボタンで, 確認画面が出る。「はい」ボタンで SDカードへ書き込み
  (直前で, 歯車ボタンでユーザー登録など可能)
- 書き込み・検証が終われば, 「続ける」ボタンで SDカードを取り出せる

Raspberry Pi側

- 最初のグラデーション
- 起動中の画面
- (ユーザー名登録が未だなら, ユーザー名登録を行う)
- インストールの続き

Raspberry Pi側の ほとんど最初のステップ(ユーザー名登録までいかない)で起動できないようなら, ダウンロードしたファイルが壊れている可能性があります, (サイトに記されている) 以下の情報確認するとよいでしょう

- File Name:  `ubuntu-mate-22.04-desktop-arm64+raspi.img.xz`
- File Size:  1.8 GB
- Checksum (SHA256)   `3b538f8462cdd957acfbab57f5d949faa607c50c3fb8e6e9d1ad13d5cd6c0c02`

また, ブート優先順位に間違いがあっても 起動しないはずはないと思われますが
必要であれば `rpi-imager` の "Misc utility images"から "SD Card Boot" を選び 復元するとよいかも

Answer (score -1):

単にインストールを失敗しているだけなんでは。
最初から新たにやり直してみては